# f# generating a next value function

Tags: recursion, f#, generator

Given a list [1, 2] I am trying to create an anonymous function that generates a tuple of
(next value * a function that generates the next value)
...  something along the lines of

```
f = createFunc([1; 2])
(v1, f1)  = f()    //v1 = Some 1
(v2, f2)  = f1()   //v2 = Some 2
(v3, f3)  = f2()   //v3 = None
```

I can do this easily enough in Elixir, but am banging my head against the wall in F#.  Any pointers gratefully received.  My attempt so far looks like:

```
let top_and_tail (l: list<'a>): (Option<'a> * list<'a>) = 
    match l with
        | [] -> (None, [])
        | h :: t -> ((Some h), t)


let rec createFun l = 
    fun() -> 
        let (h, t) = top_and_tail(l)
        (h, createFun(t))
```

Comment: What's the problem with this implementation?

Comment: my fsi (fsharpi) gives me an errorType mismatch. Expecting a
    ''a'    
but given a
    'unit -> Option<'b> * 'a'    
The types ''a' and 'unit -> Option<'b> * 'a' cannot be unified.

Comment: Have you tried annotating the type of `createFun`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add type annotation to the signature of your function.  Its return type depends on the length of `l`. You can work around it by defining a recursive type:

```
data Ret a = 
| End of a
| KeepGoing of a * (unit -> Ret a)
```

Comment: Yes, this works (even without the End constructor).  Many thanks to you and glennsl

Comment: can't format for some reason - ```
type ISLA =
    | More of (unit -> Option<int> * ISLA)
    
let top_and_tail (l: list<'a>): (Option<'a> * list<'a>) = 
    match l with
        | [] -> (None, [])
        | h :: t -> ((Some h), t)

let rec cf(l:list<int>) : (unit -> (Option<int> * ISLA)) =
    fun() ->
        let (h, t) = top_and_tail(l)
        let f = cf(t)
        (h, More f)    //(h, More cf(t)) does not work

let f = cf([1; 2; 3])    
let (v1, More f1) = f()
let (v2, More f2) = f1()
let (v3, More f3) = f2()
let (v4, More f4) = f3()
```